# Installing Chef Server on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, chef-infra

I'm trying to get a Chef Server up and running on a Windows 2008 Server box.

I'm following the process here:
http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installing+Chef+Server+Manually

I've just installed Gecode and the next step is a ruby command:

`gem install chef-server chef-server-api chef-server chef-solr`

However, running this command gives the following output suggesting that Gecode isn't installed.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>gem install chef-server chef-server-api chef-server chef-
solr
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing chef-server:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lgecodesearch... no
================================================================================
=========
Gecode >3.5 must be installed (http://www.gecode.org/).

OSX:
  brew install gecode

For convenience, we have built Gecode for Debian/Ubuntu (<release> is lucid or m
averick):
  Add the following two lines to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list:
    deb http://apt.opscode.com <release> main
    deb-src http://apt.opscode.com <release> main
  Then run:
    curl http://apt.opscode.com/packages@opscode.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add
-
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libgecode-dev

Other distributions can build from source.
================================================================================
=========
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
        --with-gecodesearchlib
        --without-gecodesearchlib
extconf.rb:57:in `<main>': Gecode not installed (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/dep_selector-0.0.8 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep_selector
-0.0.8/ext/dep_gecode/gem_make.out
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing chef-server-api:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lgecodesearch... no
================================================================================
=========
Gecode >3.5 must be installed (http://www.gecode.org/).

OSX:
  brew install gecode

For convenience, we have built Gecode for Debian/Ubuntu (<release> is lucid or m
averick):
  Add the following two lines to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list:
    deb http://apt.opscode.com <release> main
    deb-src http://apt.opscode.com <release> main
  Then run:
    curl http://apt.opscode.com/packages@opscode.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add
-
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libgecode-dev
```

I installed version 3.7.3 with the default options.

Anyone have an idea how I can proceed? I don't know anything about Ruby or Gecode.

TIA

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687349/installing-chef-server-in-windows.  I can able to install those packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef server is not supported on Windows.

Comment: This buried in this Opscode ticket - https://www.opscode.com/support/tickets/12882

Comment: Could you paste what is says in the ticket? I don't want to sign up just to read it!

Comment: @enashnash From what I see here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide+for+Windows, it looks like it *is* supported on Windows

Comment: Sorry, I thought the ticket was public. I quote Opscode support: "The Open Source Chef Server only works on Linux"

Comment: @NullUserException That guide is about setting up a chef node or management workstation. The OP is talking about setting up a chef server on windows.