# how to install chef server on windows

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I  installed **chef client on windows like msi installer** but i don't know how to install chef server on windows please suggest me

**how to install chef server on windows operating system**

Answer (score 9):

Open source Chef Server is not supported on Windows.  You can confirm this as follows:

- Go to the official download site here: https://downloads.chef.io/chef-server/
- Scroll down to see the supported operating systems.

This is not to say that it is theoretically impossible to run a Chef Server on a Windows box.  But I haven't seen credible instructions for doing it, or anyone claiming to have done it.

See also:

- [Installing Chef Server on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098330/installing-chef-server-on-windows) - which says it is not supported.

My advice would be to either bite the bullet and set up Chef Server on a Linux machine, OR fork out some money and use Opscode's Hosted Enterprise Chef ... where the server runs on Opscode's infrastructure.

Answer (score 7):

Chef server cannot be installed on a windows machine. Your **chef server should always be a 64-bit Linux machine only** and your chef client can be on any platform .